Windows 11 automatically activated to Professional Edition and I didn't do it
I have a laptop that I got from work, but they gave me a better laptop that I use for work so this laptop in the story was sitting with no utilisation.
To erase all the data on this old laptop, I removed the HDD, swapped in another HDD, and installed Linux on that. After some time I decided to switch the laptop to Windows 11. By the way, this laptop came with Windows 10 Pro.
I made a Windows 11 boot media with a USB stick using the software from the Windows 11 website. I did that and then I formatted my Linux HDD to install Windows 11. I installed Windows 11 and when I went and opened the Windows 11 activation screen it shows that it is already activated with Windows 11 Pro. I don't understand where this Windows 11 Pro key came from and on my Microsoft account that I newly created. In my microsoft account that is not linked to anything, this device comes up like this... Why is it showing that it is a Windows 11 Pro device? I was going to buy a Windows 11 license but before that I saw this.

I did slmgr /xpr and that shows this output

Is it possible that it got activated somehow from the Windows 10 Pro installation that the deivce originally came with? I had cleared the HDD (in fact it isn't even the same HDD running right now on this device) and still is it somehow being activated by the old installation? Is that possible? On the underside of the device there is a Windows 10 Pro sticker.
Activation state in the System > Activation looks like this:


What exactly is the problem though?  What are you trying to fix?

I need to know if this device is being tracked. I got it for my use because I was given another laptop. But now that I switched it from Windows 10 Pro to Linux and then to Windows 11, I need to know if this Windows 11 Pro activation is going to cause issues..

@AadirajAnil - It’s not being tracked by Microsoft. Windows 10 and Windows 11 have supported digital activation since their respective releases. Windows 11 supports being activated by Windows 10 licenses. The license to Windows is embedded into the motherboard firmware. This has been the case for more than 2 decades with the release of Windows 8.

But this license isn't mine, that's the exact reason I got rid of Windows 10 in the first place and switched to Linux... So now I installed Windows 11, why has it persisted and got me this Windows Pro license? I want to activate it with my own license... Also now that it got activated once with my Windows 10 Pro license, can the organisation see that I have activated this device with Windows 11? Or is that a Microsoft thing?

@AadirajAnil - The license came with the laptop it cannot be transferred. You installed Windows and you didn’t use the documented method, to indicate you wanted to use a different license key, you can unregister the license and register a different key if you really wanted to use a different key. Your organization has no way to track your device if they didn’t image the device. You would only be a gray area if you were using an enterprise key, but that isn’t the case, your using an OEM license.

Here is how you would install Windows 10 or Windows 11 with a different key. If that question answers your question I will flag it as a duplicate

So since it is an OEM license, the organization cannot track the device? So what does the change product license option in the system > activation menu do?

@AadirajAnil - You would change the license key. I will point out the OEM license is permanently linked to the device. So if you were given the device, you were also given the license, the OEM license cannot be transferred to another device. The organization not being able to track the device has nothing to do with the type of license it is only that you were in total control of the installation of Windows.

@Ramhound, I am ok with using the OEM license, I cannot use the Enterprise license if that's a thing, that's all

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@DanielB, I have attached that image now

This is expected behavior (as is the auto-activation, as Windows ≥10 is activated upon running Windows Update) - devices with a Windows 10 Pro license attached to their motherboard hardware ID are auto-activated with a Windows 11 Pro license when they were upgraded or clean installed with Windows 11 (the only issue that may potentially exist is if Home was selected during install and not Pro, a repair install of Pro should be done since it's the most efficient way to get the features of Pro that Home does not have - e.g. gpedit.msc, Hyper-V, etc.)
